# Multiple bash command in Nomad

Tags: python, bash, nomad

I have an application that runs multiple Python scripts in order. I can run them in docker-compose as follow:

```
command: >
  bash -c "python -m module_a &&
  python -m module_b &&
  python -m module_c"
```

Now I'm, scheduling the job in Nomad, and added the below command under configuration for Docker driver:

```
command = "/bin/bash"
args = ["-c", "python -m module_a", "&&","
      "python -m module_b", "&&",
      "python -m module_c"]
```

But Nomad seems to escape `&&`, and just runs the first module, and issue exit code 0. Is there any way to run the multiline command similar to docker-compose?

Comment: The `&&` is passed as an extra argument to the shell, not as code to run.

Comment: you have an extra " in the first line of your args array.

Answer (score 3):

The following is guaranteed to work with the `exec` driver:

```
command = "/bin/bash"
args = [
  "-c",                                                  ## next argument is a shell script
  "for module; do python -m \"$module\" || exit; done",  ## this is that script.
  "_",                                                   ## passed as $0 to the script
  "module_a", "module_b", "module_c"                     ## passed as $1, $2, and $3
]
```

Note that *only a single argument* is passed as a script -- the one immediately following `-c`. Subsequent arguments are *arguments to that script*, not additional scripts or script fragments.

---

Even simpler, you could run:

```
command = "/bin/bash"
args = ["-c", "python -m module_a && python -m module_b && python -m module_c" ]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I actually tried this, but either methods results in exit code 2: `Exit Code: 2, Exit Message: "Docker container exited with non-zero exit code: 2"`

Comment: I don't suppose making it `-xc` rather than `-c` (thus logging commands run to stderr) might be enlightening?

Comment: (Without a log saying otherwise, "exit code: 2" could mean that one of the Python modules was successfully started and then exited with that status due to an environmental or installation difference between your prior environment and this one.)

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue. I can run both with `docker run -it <IMAGEID> /bin/bash -c 'python -m module_a && python -m module_b && python -m module_c'` and it seems to run both. Maybe Nomad doesn't provide full shell?

Comment: With this (array) usage, Nomad doesn't provide any shell at all. The `/bin/bash` target on your executable is used.

Comment: Any other recommendation on how to run these modules in order? Even if I can run them as separate periodic tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157141/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-seemvision).